# SharePoint lists and views

Tags: 2010

I created a simple list with the capability of creating folders.  The default view shows the selectable folder names (only).

Problem:

When I select the folder, it opens the associated list of entrys, however I want to automatically view these entrys using a different view showing the other associated fields etc...

Interenstingly enough, I really want to create a one to many relationship; but havent the time to dig into this.  Unless someone can give me some quick pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to go into the View settings and expand the Folders section and set it to Show all items without folders.